# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'

Tags: python

```
tushar@tushar:~/ghost$ sudo ghost
[sudo] password for tushar: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ghost", line 9, in <module>
    import readline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
```

Here another try.

```
tushar@tushar:~/ghost$ 
tushar@tushar:~/ghost$ sudo ghost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ghost", line 9, in <module>
    import readline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'
tushar@tushar:~/ghost$
```

I got this error but i already installed readline ...

```
tushar@tushar:~$ pip install readline
/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/py2_warn.py:21: UserWarning: Setuptools will stop working on Python 2
```

> You are running Setuptools on Python 2, which is no longer supported
> and  SETUPTOOLS WILL STOP WORKING in a subsequent release (no sooner
> than 2020-04-20). Please ensure you are installing Setuptools using
> pip 9.x or later or pin to `setuptools<45` in your environment. If you
> have done those things and are still encountering this message, please
> follow up at
>
> **WARNING:** pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip. Please see
> https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the
> underlying issue. To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m
> pip' instead of running pip directly. DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached
> the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python
> as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will
> drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in
> pip, can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> Requirement already satisfied: readline in
> ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (6.2.4.1) tushar@tushar:~$

Comment: Try to use `pip3`. It seems like you are installing Python 2 packeges

Comment: The long term solution, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910393/7867968) is to use `python -m pip install <module>` to ensure you are using the correct pip/python

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt install libreadline-dev
```

or

```
pip install readline
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably just for Linux, right?

"Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
error: this module is not meant to work on Windows
[end of output]"

TY!

Edit: that's the Win readline version
"pyreadline3"

So just run:

$pip install pyreadline3

And you're done :)